# Merging two correlated dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Data science isn't my specialty so forgive whatever ignorance I have in this post.

I have two years worth of madden football stats that I would like to correlate as one with the goal of knowing which Attribute correlates to which stat (i.e. players with a high catch rating tend to have more receptions and yards). I have the two individual correlation matrices but I would like a correlation of both years together to paint a better picture of which attributes really matter.

Below is a sample of the data sets I have

| Name | REC | YDS | AVG | TD | YAC | DROPS | LONG | AGE | SPEED | ACCELERATION | STRENGTH | AWARENESS | AGILITY | CATCH | CARRY | JUMP | BREAK TACKLE | TACKLE | THROW POWER | THROW ACC | PASS BLOCK | RUN BLOCK | KICK POWER | KICK ACCURACY | IMPORTANCE | STAMINA | KICK RETURN | INJURY | TOUGHNESS | PLAYER EGO | POSITION | WEIGHT | HEIGHT | HGTIN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ANTONIO BROWN | 49 | 730 | 14.90 | 5 | 148 | 8 | 70 | 33 | 88 | 91 | 49 | 97 | 96 | 94 | 65 | 80 | 40 | 10 | 20 | 20 | 13 | 14 | 20 | 20 | 80 | 91 | 25 | 72 | 64 | 99 | WR | 185 | 5'10 | 70 |
| RASHAD GREENE | 64 | 857 | 13.39 | 7 | 246 | 5 | 80 | 28 | 87 | 90 | 45 | 89 | 93 | 89 | 63 | 81 | 39 | 15 | 20 | 20 | 20 | 24 | 20 | 20 | 80 | 96 | 40 | 76 | 81 | 25 | WR | 185 | 5'11 | 71 |
| TRISHTON JACKSON | 111 | 1648 | 14.85 | 9 | 454 | 11 | 86 | 23 | 87 | 90 | 53 | 72 | 88 | 81 | 64 | 90 | 46 | 20 | 20 | 20 | 16 | 16 | 20 | 20 | 80 | 96 | 35 | 85 | 78 | 35 | WR | 191 | 6'1 | 73 |

This goes on for about 200 rows and I will have two separate data sets for each year, same exact column headers/ different data (stats obviously change year to year but so do the attribute values, a QB gets old his arm strength goes down)

I'm using Pandas to create the dataframe and run correlation on each individual data set

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name', 'REC', 'YDS', 'AVG', 'LONG', 'TD', 'DROPS', 'YAC',
                                    'AGE',
                                    'SPEED', 'ACCELERATION', 'STRENGTH', 'AWARENESS',
                                    'AGILITY', 'CATCH', 'CARRY', 'JUMP', 'BREAK TACKLE', 'TACKLE',
                                    'PASS BLOCK', 'RUN BLOCK', 'TOUGHNESS', 'WEIGHT', 'HGTIN'])
df = df.dropna(subset=['REC'])
df.corr()
```

But how can I combine these two, and eventually more years worth of data, to see the complete picture?

Comment: What is your expected output? Can you include a minimum reproducible example with about 5 columns and 3 rows for each input DataFrame and the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load each year’s data into separate data frames. Then, you can use Pandas' concat function to concatenate the dataframes vertically to combine the data for multiple years so that you have a single dataframe for all the years. Once you have this, you can simply calculate the correlation.

Here is a simple example. see if it helps you.

```
import pandas as pd

# Simple data for few years for testing
year1 = [
    ["Player1", 50, 700, 15.0, 4],
    ["Player2", 60, 800, 13.3, 5],
]

year2 = [
    ["Player1", 55, 750, 14.5, 3],
    ["Player2", 65, 900, 12.7, 6],
]

columns = ['Name', 'REC', 'YDS', 'AVG', 'TD']
df_year1 = pd.DataFrame(year1, columns=columns)
df_year2 = pd.DataFrame(year2, columns=columns)
all_years_df = pd.concat([df_year1, df_year2])
correlation_matrix = all_years_df.corr()
```

You can use the following code to create a simple heatmap to visualize the correlation.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))
sns.heatmap(correlation_matrix, annot=True, cmap='coolwarm', vmin=-1, vmax=1)
plt.title('Correlation Matrix')
plt.show()
```

Comment: This was what I was looking for. I attempted this before but I had pd.concact([df_year1, df_year2], axis=1) and it doubled the size of my dataframe. Removing the axis = 1 did exactly what I was hoping for